# How to mirror ftp server directories having two partitions one of them almost full?

Tags: curl, ftp, wget, rsync, mirror

I've got a repository in a partition almost full. It have been wget -m(mirroring) with an ftp server. Now it is full my local repository and I have to start using another partition.

It was wget -m because from time to time there are changes in older directories besides adding new directories every day in the ftp server.

I would need to "synchronize" ftp server with the old partition and copy the new files to the new partition.  cannot delete at the ftp server or make changes.

I have read -m is equivalent to -r -N -l and -N is not compatible with -O(--output-document), so I used -P (--directory-prefix). I really need -o (--output-file) to ingest the new output files in the directory to a bbdd.

I have read the man pages of wget and curl. rsync is only for ssh?  and the samples of timestamp http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_5.html are not clear for me.   https://everything.curl.dev/ftp

I am stuck at the point that I only get a new mirror in the new partition. But I do not want to duplicate the info:

wget  --directory-prefix=/export/d-4/ --mirror --output-file=/export/d-4/download/download_log280922.txt --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=pwd ftp://ftp....:21/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> rsync is only for ssh?

This is not strictly true, [`rsync` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) claims that

> Note that rsync must be installed on both the source and destination
> machines.

So if you are working with remote server which is just FTP then `rsync` is not useful.

> copy the new files to the new partition

If you just need files which were modified no later than X units of time ago you might find `find` command useful, for example

```
find . -type f -mtime -3
```

will print files in current directories and its' subdirectories which were modified 72 h (3*24 h) or less ago

Comment: How to combine  find and wget commands?  The equivalent  -mtime 3 at wget would be? Thank you